# how to get original fragment color in fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, jogl, fragment-shader

I am writing a tile based image viewer for my application using JOGL. The image is divided in the grid of tiles. I am rendering textures for each tile based on the current zoom scale.
My each tile rendering code looks like following:

```
double projectedX = ... //will calculate the X location of tile on the screen
double projectedY = ... //will calculate the Y location of tile on the screen
double projectedWidth = ... //calculate width of the tile based on scale
double projectedHeight= ... //calculate height of the tile based on scale

gl.glTranslated(projectedX, projectedY, 0.0);
gl.glScaled( scale, scale, 1.0);

texture.bing(gl);  //here, the texture is of tile image which is created in a shared context in background. There are several texture already created one for each tile.
texture.enable(gl);

double s2 = iw * (1.0 / texture.getWidth());
double t2 = ih * ( 1.0 / texture.getHeight());

//draw the texture
gl.glBegin( GL2.GL_QUADS );
gl.glTexCoord2d( 0, 0 );
gl.glVertex2d( 0, 0 );
gl.glTexCoord2d( 0, t2 );
gl.glVertex2d( 0, ih );
gl.glTexCoord2d( s2, t2 );
gl.glVertex2d( iw, ih );
gl.glTexCoord2d( s2, 0 );
gl.glVertex2d( iw, 0 );
gl.glEnd();
texture.disable(gl);
```

Now, I want to add fragment shader in the viewer to implement brightness, white balancing features. For that, in the fragment shader, first I need to get the original pixel color of the texture and then apply the color correction algorithm. But I am not sure how to do it. How do I get the current texture being rendered and its current pixel co-ordinates in the fragment shader?

Comment: Look,I would vote for closing this question.I won't because I don't like when people do it to me.So I will explain what's wrong with your question;SO format implies that you come to ask questions after you tried solving it on your own.Your question clearly shows you haven't tried.You are looking for example how to use shaders in OpenGL,right?So google a little and you will find tons of resources.Here is the place to ask help for specific problems.SO is not a tutorial marketplace.Btw,if you wanna use shaders,begin from dropping the deprecated OpenGL API.

Comment: I tried a lot on various tutorials, OpenGL community sites but everywhere they explained about a simple case of sampling on Texture0 in the fragment shader. My case is different where I have multiple textures and I could get a good example explaining this case. That's why as a last resort I put the question here. Do you think I am using deprecated OpenGL API? could you please point me that?

Comment: Hi Amay, I would suggest to add what you wrote in the comment in your question. Anyway, you should take a look at the [Hello Triangle](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_Tutorial#Hello_Triangle) example in order to have a first look of what is the modern opengl.

Answer (score 1):

You use the immediate mode (glBegin, glEnd, glVertex, ...) which is inefficient and completely obsolete. Even Quake 2 uses the retained mode.

Using immediate mode wouldn't be a good idea even if you targeted only OpenGL 1.2. Moreover, you might be bothered by some unfixed and very old bugs only occurring when mixing shaders with this rendering mode. Numerous drivers emulate it with dynamic VBOs under the hood with more or less success :s It depends on which hardware you target but please use at least the VBOs.

Use some GLSL code to get the "color" of the pixel coming from the texture in a fragment shader: texture2D(mySampler2D_1, gl_TexCoord[0].st);

texture2D is a built-in function used to retrieve a particular texel from a sampler. Declare a uniform sample2D per texture unit and use glGetUniformLocation + glUniform1. Don't forget to call glActiveTexture and glBindTexture or Texture.bind() for each unit.

I advise you to look at this if you look for build-in input variables of a fragment shader:
https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Built-in_Variable_%28GLSL%29#Fragment_shader_inputs

gl_SampleID might be useful in your case.